# how much rep do i need to edit questions and have the edit take effect immediately?

Tags: discussion

i'm not used to having my DSP or EE expertise questioned like this.  i don't even have the problem at the math SE or the physics SE.

Comment: I'd argue that you should learn to capitalize things before you start editing.

Comment: sometimes i do.  depends on how formal of an answer i am writing.

Answer (score 2):

This is covered in the Privileges section of the Help Center; it's [2,000 reputation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit).

> #### Edit questions and answers
>
> Privilege type: Moderation privilege
> Awarded at: 2,000 reputation
>
> #### What is edit questions and answers?
>
> We believe in the power of community editing. That means once you've generated enough reputation, we trust you to edit *anything* in the system without it going through peer review. Not just your posts—*anyone's posts*!

Note that *anything* is not entirely true; you can't edit tag wikis and excerpts unsupervised, you need [20,000 reputation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) for that.

Comment: Don't  such edits go into an editing queue for approvals?

Comment: 'Such edits' – do you mean edits on regular posts (questions and answers)? Once you have 2k reputation you bypass the queue. That's the essence of the privilege I quoted.

Comment: It's also site based, so you need at least 2000 *at that site* for you to earn the privilege